# Can Someone Explain me the below Code?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Now my question is:

1) what the use of Order.php and why he create? and how can i store the Refrence of $order with the Object?

2) And please describe the code(i know the comment is already there but i need help )
Now Main.php:

```
<?php
include("Order.php");
include("connect.php");
$query="SELECT * FROM `orders`";
$filter_Result=mysqli_query($con,$query);
$newOrders=Array();
$items = array();     

while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($filter_Result))
{
$order;
$orderId= $row['id']; //fetch row id
echo "hello".$orderId;
if(in_array($orderId,$newOrders,true)){
 //we already created an array object for this id..use it
 $order=<get order object from $newOrders for which id is $orderId>
}
else{
$order=new Order($row['id'], $row['tableId'], $row['createdDate']);
//$newOrders.AddToArray($order);
array_push($newOrders,$order);
}
$item=new Item($row['ProductId'], $row['ProductName'], $row['Quantity']);

$Order.AddItem($item);

}
foreach($order as $newOrders)
{
//create box


}
include("Modal.php");
?>
```

now Order.php:

```
<?php
 class Order {
  /* Member variables */
  var $orderId;
  var $orderTime;
  var $tableNumber;
  var $items = array();   

  function __Order($orderId, $orderTime, $tableNumber)
  {
      $this->$orderId = $orderId;
      $this->$orderTime = $orderTime;
      $this->$tableNumber = $tableNumber;
  }   
  function AddItem($itemId, $itemName, $quantity, $personalization)   
  {
       $item = new Item($itemId, $itemName, $quantity, $personalization);
      $items[] = $item;
  }
}

class Item {
    var $productId;
    var $productName;
    var $quantity;
    var $personalization;

    function __Item($productId, $productName, $quantity, $personalization)
    {
        $this->$productId = $productId;
        $this->$productName = $productName;
        $this->$quantity = $quantity;
        $this->$personalization = $personalization;
    }
}
```

?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He created the Order.php to keep the class elements external from the main code. This is cleaner code and easier to maintain.

*and how can i store the Refrence of $order with the Object?* You are already storing this in `$newOrders`?

Added comments to each line for main.php

```
<?php
// these includes are just bringing in code from external files. Nothing much really to say here.
include("Order.php");
include("connect.php");

//$query is just setting up the SQL query to the database for selecting all columns from a table called orders.
$query="SELECT * FROM `orders`";

//$filter_Results is just saving the query in a variable, this is used later on to fetch the data in a while loop
$filter_Result=mysqli_query($con,$query);

//$newOrders and $items = array() is just pre-defining these variables as arrays.
$newOrders=Array();
$items = array();     

//As said before, we need to use a while loop to extract the data fetched from sql where `mysqli_fetch_array` is the method of retrieving the data.
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($filter_Result))
{
    $order; //Not sure what the next line is doing.. `$order;` doesn't do anything..
    $orderId= $row['id']; //Saving the column name `id` as a variable $orderID
    echo "hello".$orderId; //echo out the hello# where # is the orderID

    //This is checking if the orderID retrieved from sql has already been placed inside the $newOrders array returning true or false.
    if(in_array($orderId,$newOrders,true)){

        //Some more code needs to be added here, I'm guessing you need to add in something to find the object relating to the `orderID` that already exists in `$newOrders`
        $order=<get order object from $newOrders for which id is $orderId>
    }

    // If $orderID not in $newOrders
    else{
        // Create a new instance of Order class called $order
        $order=new Order($row['id'], $row['tableId'], $row['createdDate']);

        //Add this order to the array $newOrders
        array_push($newOrders,$order);
    }
    // Create a new instance of the Item class called $item takinging in the columns ProductId, ProductName, Quantity
    $item=new Item($row['ProductId'], $row['ProductName'], $row['Quantity']);

    // Using a method from orders called AddItem (this can be found in Order.php under the order class
    $Order.AddItem($item);
}

// Looping through each order inside $newOrders (although this seems wrong, should be foreach($newOrders as $order)
foreach($order as $newOrders)
{
//create box
}

/ Finally including some more code inside the Modal.php file
include("Modal.php");
?>
```

Order.php

```
<?php

// Class called Order
 class Order {

  // properties of the class.
  var $orderId;
  var $orderTime;
  var $tableNumber;
  var $items = array();   

  // Function inside the method which fills the properties upon creating a new instance the class `$order=new Order($row['id'], $row['tableId'], $row['createdDate']);` 
  function __Order($orderId, $orderTime, $tableNumber)
  {
      // Using the parameters passed to the function to fill the properties of the class
      $this->$orderId = $orderId;
      $this->$orderTime = $orderTime;
      $this->$tableNumber = $tableNumber;
  }   

  //Function called AddItem which takes parameters and fills an items array however this should be using $this->
  function AddItem($itemId, $itemName, $quantity, $personalization)   
  {
       $item = new Item($itemId, $itemName, $quantity, $personalization);
      $items[] = $item;
  }
}

// New class called Item
class Item {

    // properties of the class.
    var $productId;
    var $productName;
    var $quantity;
    var $personalization;

    // Same as above: Function inside the method which fills the properties upon creating a new instance the class
    function __Item($productId, $productName, $quantity, $personalization)
    {
        $this->$productId = $productId;
        $this->$productName = $productName;
        $this->$quantity = $quantity;
        $this->$personalization = $personalization;
    }
}
?>
```

To answer your question:

1. An array of objects just means you are creating a new instance of the object and then saving the object in an array. You are already doing this with your `$newOrders` array. You have created a new `$order` (the object) and then saved it in the array `$newOrders` using: `array_push($newOrders,$order);`
2. Not really sure what you are asking for here? Where has this code come from? Is this a tutorial of some sort?

Comment: Sir, I have an question,can you describe what is the meaning of below two line and how can i do that:
1) //Declare array of 'order' object - the one you created in php.
2) //You may want to use <key,value> pair type of array in php - if that works as hashtable.

Comment: @DevelopmentTechlab added answer to bottom of my answer; however not sure what you are asking in 2)

Comment: If i want to create the array of 'Order' object in main .php .................. 
$Order = array();
$Order=new Order();
 so it's right or not

Comment: @Development Techlab you already have an array of objects why do you need to make a second? But otherwise `$Order[] = new Order();` would suffice